# How to view .net/mono framework class hierarchy?

Tags: visual-studio, monodevelop, class-hierarchy, objectbrowser

The two basic views in Visual Studio's ObjectBrowser and Monodevelop's Assembly browsers are Namespaces and Assembly based. How to get to a class hierarchy based view of the frameworks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) (free or paid).
Expand the Derived Types node under any type to see all inherited types in the currently open assemblies.